# Genera números aleatorios de menor a mayor separados por comas

Tags: php

Cómo generar números aleatorios de menor a mayor, hasta 5 números separados por comas.

Estoy usando for() de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
for($g = 1; $g <= 5; $g++){
    
}
?>
```

Combinado con la función `rand()` nativa de PHP. Pero, ¿cómo aplico `rand()` para que me traiga los resultados de la siguiente manera? Creo que el rand() solo devolverá 1 número y no como resultado a continuación:

```
1, 5, 11, 29, 90
3, 6, 10, 22, 81
.....
```

Hay alguna otra manera de hacer esto?

Perdona mi español.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que podrías hacerlo con un par de bucles anidados y un array que posteriormente ordenas y muestras con `implode()`:

```
<?php
for($j=0;$j<2;$j++){
    $a=[];
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
        $a[]=rand(0,100);
    sort($a);
    echo '<div>'.implode(', ',$a).'</div>';
}
```

Obteniendo algo así:

```
6, 10, 20, 63, 74
6, 14, 19, 22, 47
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Usar [`range()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.range.php) para generar un array de números dentro de un rango.
2. Usar [`array_rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-rand.php) combinado con [`array_flip()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-flip.php) para obtener el valor (en lugar de las claves) de los 5 elementos que necesites ([fuente](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-rand.php#93834))
3. Usar [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) para mostrarlos separados por coma.

Por ejemplo:

```
$numbers = range(1, 100);
$random=implode(",",array_rand(array_flip($numbers), 5));
echo $random;
```

**Salida:**

```
12,22,66,90,93  # O lo que toque, siempre en orden
```

Si necesitas varios conjuntos de valores, puedes crear tu propia función y llamarla, pasándole los parámetros adecuados.

Veamos un ejemplo de función personalizada:

```
/**

 * Genera números random ordenados y separados por coma

 * @param int $min valor mínimo para el rango

 * @param int $max valor máximo para el rango
 
 * @param int $items número de grupos de items a generar 

 * @param int $limit límite de elementos a extraer del rango
 
 * @return array con valores separados por coma

 */
function sortedRandom($min, $max, $items, $limit){
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    $randoms=array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $items; $i++) {
        $randoms[]=implode(",",array_rand(array_flip($numbers), $limit));
    }
    return $randoms;
}
```

Hagamos una prueba:

```
$randoms=sortedRandom(1,100,2,5);
var_dump($randoms);
```

**Salida:**

En `$randoms` tendrás algo así más o menos, que puedes mostrar o utilizar según necesites:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "6,16,33,69,74"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "20,28,35,64,81"
}
```